# Pulling data from specific workbooks and corresponding worksheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a folder that I pull data from manually but would like to automate this task. One folder has a workbook for every week for the year

PH Daily DT WK47.xls
PH Daily DT WK48.xls
PH Daily DT WK49.xls

In this workbook, it has info that looks like this

Date(col1)     Value (col2)

Monday     #

Tuesday

Wednesday#

Thursday #

Friday   #

Saturday #

Sunday   #

If I wanted to pull a value from the cell corresponding to the day in week 47 until the next monday is reached - in this case  week 48 - to continue the process, how could I go about doing this? In my head this is what Im thinking

Pull Monday Data from PH Daily DT WK47.xls
 Pull Tuesday Data from PH Daily DT WK47.xls
*
*
Pull Sunday Data from PH Daily DT WK47.xls
Pull Monday Data from PH Daily DT WK(n+1).xls

But obviously we cant put a formula in the middle of a destination folder. Thansk for your help! Please let me know if its not clear enough and I will try my best to explain in more depth

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 0):

You can create "PH Daily DT WK47.xls" using something like:

```
 filename = "PH Daily DT WK" & weeknumber &".XLS"
```

Where weeknumber is a variable

You can loop weeknumber through a range of values using

```
  For WeekNumber = 1 to 52
```

Have a go writing your code using those two ideas and let us know when you get stuck:

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware you could do that with VBA, R has something very similar. Appreciate it my friend!